# How to troubleshoot a wireless interface that is operationally down?

Tags: debian, wifi, network-interface

After upgrading from [Debian buster](https://www.debian.org/releases/bustert/)(10) to [bullseye](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/)(11), my [Ath10k](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k) card [Compex WLE900VX IEEE 802.11ac/a/b/g/n](https://www.apu-board.de/produkte/compexwle900vx.html) no longer comes up. Running `ip a` shows an UP administrative state, but a DOWN operational state:

```
wlp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
```

**I have now reverted the Debian upgrade, performing a clean installation of Debian buster, but the problem persists.**

Clients are unable to see the wireless network, so it does appear to be down. Previously this worked fine, with the Debian upgrade the only change.

`dmesg | grep wlp3s0` last lines:

```
[   13.616576] device wlp3s0 entered promiscuous mode
[   37.410198] device wlp3s0 left promiscuous mode
[   37.414949] br0: port 2(wlp3s0) entered disabled state
```

`dmesg | grep wlp3s0` last lines **on an identical device that's working**:

```
[   18.914881] device wlp3s0 entered promiscuous mode
[   22.303753] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[   22.310361] br0: port 2(wlp3s0) entered blocking state
[   22.315651] br0: port 2(wlp3s0) entered forwarding state
```

`dmesg | grep ath10k`:

```
[    8.719417] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    8.898596] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin (-2)
[    8.920241] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin (-2)
[    8.940058] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-6.bin (-2)
[    8.951931] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-5.bin
[    8.962553] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca988x hw2.0 target 0x4100016c chip_id 0x043202ff sub 0000:0000
[    9.003670] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 0 tracing 0 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    9.004463] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver 10.2.4-1.0-00041 api 5 features no-p2p,raw-mode,mfp,allows-mesh-bcast crc32 f43fa422
[    9.059335] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board-2.bin (-2)
[    9.069730] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board.bin
[    9.079936] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: board_file api 1 bmi_id N/A crc32 bebc7c08
[   10.234730] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: htt-ver 2.1 wmi-op 5 htt-op 2 cal otp max-sta 128 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[   13.559842] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pdev param 0 not supported by firmware
```

Relevant lines from `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# Wired
auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet manual

# Wireless
auto wlp3s0
iface wlp3s0 inet manual

# Bridge - note that wlp3s0 will be added to bridge_ports by hostapd
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports enp1s0
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

My device entry from `lspci`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA986x/988x 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
```

`iw dev`:

```
Interface wlp3s0
  ifindex 5
  wdev 0x1
  addr 04:f0:21:88:34:71
  type managed
  txpower 0.00 dBm
  multicast TXQ:
    qsz-byt qsz-pkt flows   drops   marks   overlmt hashcol tx-bytes    tx-packets
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0       0
```

`tail /var/log/syslog` after a `systemctl restart networking`:

```
Jun 18 10:55:42 host1 systemd[1]: Stopping Raise network interfaces...
Jun 18 10:55:42 host1 kernel: [244432.725354] br0: port 1(enp1s0) entered disabled state
Jun 18 10:55:42 host1 kernel: [244432.786836] device enp1s0 left promiscuous mode
Jun 18 10:55:42 host1 kernel: [244432.791588] br0: port 1(enp1s0) entered disabled state
Jun 18 10:55:42 host1 kernel: [244432.826363] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
Jun 18 10:55:42 host1 systemd[1]: networking.service: Succeeded.
Jun 18 10:55:42 host1 systemd[1]: Stopped Raise network interfaces.
Jun 18 10:55:42 host1 systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Jun 18 10:55:42 host1 kernel: [244433.133733] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
Jun 18 10:55:43 host1 systemd-udevd[2403]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.
Jun 18 10:55:43 host1 systemd-udevd[2403]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jun 18 10:55:43 host1 systemd-udevd[2403]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for br0: No such file or directory
Jun 18 10:55:43 host1 kernel: [244433.205584] br0: port 1(enp1s0) entered blocking state
Jun 18 10:55:43 host1 kernel: [244433.211051] br0: port 1(enp1s0) entered disabled state
Jun 18 10:55:43 host1 kernel: [244433.216938] device enp1s0 entered promiscuous mode
Jun 18 10:55:43 host1 kernel: [244433.234966] br0: port 1(enp1s0) entered blocking state
```

`iw list` output is exactly the same between the identical broken and working machines:

```
Wiphy phy0
    max # scan SSIDs: 16
    max scan IEs length: 195 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
    max # match sets: 0
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: -1
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
        * CMAC-256 (00-0f-ac:13)
        * GMAC-128 (00-0f-ac:11)
        * GMAC-256 (00-0f-ac:12)
    Available Antennas: TX 0x7 RX 0x7
    Configured Antennas: TX 0x7 RX 0x7
    Supported interface modes:
         * managed
         * AP
         * monitor
         * mesh point
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x19ef
            RX LDPC
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-23
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (disabled)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (disabled)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
    Band 2:
        Capabilities: 0x19ef
            RX LDPC
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-23
        VHT Capabilities (0x338001b2):
            Max MPDU length: 11454
            Supported Channel Width: neither 160 nor 80+80
            RX LDPC
            short GI (80 MHz)
            TX STBC
            RX antenna pattern consistency
            TX antenna pattern consistency
        VHT RX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: MCS 0-9
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        VHT TX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: MCS 0-9
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5180 MHz [36] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (disabled)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (disabled)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (disabled)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (disabled)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (disabled)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (disabled)
            * 5845 MHz [169] (disabled)
            * 5865 MHz [173] (disabled)
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * start_ap
         * new_station
         * new_mpath
         * set_mesh_config
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * join_mesh
         * remain_on_channel
         * set_tx_bitrate_mask
         * frame
         * frame_wait_cancel
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * set_channel
         * set_wds_peer
         * probe_client
         * set_noack_map
         * register_beacons
         * start_p2p_device
         * set_mcast_rate
         * connect
         * disconnect
         * channel_switch
         * set_qos_map
         * set_multicast_to_unicast
    Supported TX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * managed: 0x40 0xd0
         * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
    software interface modes (can always be added):
         * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ AP, mesh point } <= 8, #{ managed } <= 1,
           total <= 8, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
    HT Capability overrides:
         * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
         * maximum A-MSDU length
         * supported channel width
         * short GI for 40 MHz
         * max A-MPDU length exponent
         * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
    Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
    Device supports scan flush.
    Device supports AP scan.
    Device supports per-vif TX power setting
    Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
    Driver supports a userspace MPM
    Driver/device bandwidth changes during BSS lifetime (AP/GO mode)
    Device supports static SMPS
    Device supports configuring vdev MAC-addr on create.
    Supported extended features:
        * [ VHT_IBSS ]: VHT-IBSS
        * [ RRM ]: RRM
        * [ SET_SCAN_DWELL ]: scan dwell setting
        * [ FILS_STA ]: STA FILS (Fast Initial Link Setup)
        * [ CQM_RSSI_LIST ]: multiple CQM_RSSI_THOLD records
        * [ CONTROL_PORT_OVER_NL80211 ]: control port over nl80211
        * [ TXQS ]: FQ-CoDel-enabled intermediate TXQs
```

Comment: @CinaedSimson Hi Cinaed, I didn't (manually) change any configuration files, including `/etc/network/interfaces` during the Debian upgrade from buster to bullseye.

Comment: Okay, I was reading the first line in dmesg which indicated "wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0". Then try "rfkill unblock wan".

Comment: For debugging it might also be useful to remove wlp3s0 from the bridge and run `hostapd` directly on it, to (1) see if the behaviour changes or (2) there are any error messages. Also, look in the syslog for error messages from hostapd.

Comment: @dirkt I removed the bridge from `/etc/network/interfaces` and left the wireless interface manually configured, but the interface remains operationally DOWN

Comment: Eh, the point of the first two steps was to **run hostapd directly**, and check error messages. The first two steps alone certainly are not going to fix anything ... You need to debug this somehow. And I second the "possible driver problem".

Answer (score 4):

I have the same [Wifi-Card](https://www.apu-board.de/produkte/compexwle900vx.html) and had a very similar sounding problem with that and all my other Atheros Ath10k Wifi devices after upgrading to a Debian kernel newer than the one delivered with Buster, that required patching ath.ko.

From what i could glean at the time, the problem was that somewhere between Buster kernel and Bullseye kernel the channel selection and region code was updated, and **All** my Atheros cards had **0** available frequencies for modes other than client station on 5Ghz after that "update".

The kernel source provides an option to enable the user to override broken region detection, but Debian doesn't enable the option in kernel build.

So, both bad options I saw at the time were:

- Recompile ath.ko with neutered region detection (5 line patch from openwrt) -> 10 minute job.
- Recompile entire kernel with Option "CERTIFICATION_ONUS" set to "Let the owner of the system decide" -> Much longer compile time & requires reboot.

Both will produce "tainted kernel" warnings, and will require attention during package updates so as to catch updates to kernel source and wpa_supplicant to recompile them both before reboot to have working wifi.

As much as a I enjoy Debian, Wifi is painful on Debian.

I consider this a "dirty workaround", but haven't had the time to research the proper solution, which I suspect being something like "Add your key to secure-boot uefi config, recompile&sign kernel/modules with apt-hooks after updates, pray for no 'tainted' warnings".

Without the patch to atk.ko, all the 5Ghz frequencies in the Output of `iw phy` had `NO-IR` set.

If this works for you, I can polish up the scripts/patches I have, and edit them into this post.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Why do you think my clean install of Buster didn't resolve the problem? Is the channel selection and region code update somehow made persistent on the wireless card itself?

Comment: @rcampbell So you are confirming, that the difference between the old working kernel (on the still working identical system) and the new broken kernel is the `[NO-IR]` flag on all 5Ghz channels? As for why it's persistent, i think i remember somebody theorizing on Openwrt IRC, that the firmware has the capability to update the EEPROM. And then the new kernel says: "Hey, i can't correctly read your flash EEPROM, you are thus in a region with disallowed 5Ghz". And the firmware replies "RIght, thanks, i'll update the EEPROM with the new info, but just this once. Aaaaand now it's permanent. BYE!"

Comment: I don't believe so. I've added `iw list` output above, and it's identical between the broken and working machines. Many channels have no IR, but some are available. I believe this was always the case due to the regulatory domain I'm in, but not positive.

Comment: Well, after an upgrade from buster to bullseye, I'm hit with the same bug. All 5GHz channels are now NO-IR. I have a Compex 600 with AR928X. Can you please link to the patches you used?

Comment: Btw, there is already a bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=959821 where it says that the commit shall be reverted (but that was 05.2020)